# OnNewIntent is not called NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, onnewintent

I am creating a simple Android mobile application that reads data from an NFC Tag.  i want my application to be opened once it has detected that an NFC tag was tapped. I can't figure out what I might've missed on my code. When I try to tap an NFC Tag, it keeps on opening the Google Play Store.

**AnroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ItemDetailsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".NFCActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**NFCActivity**

```
public class NFCActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "[NFCActivity]";
public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private Context context;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] readTagFilters;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_details);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
            0);

    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter((NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED));
    IntentFilter discovery = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter techDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

    readTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{discovery};
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG, "onResume");

    if(checkIfNfcEnableAndCapable()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Phone is NFC capable and NFC is enabled.");
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, readTagFilters, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause");

    if(checkIfNfcEnableAndCapable()) {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "handleIntent");

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.v(TAG, "action: " + action);

    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        String type = intent.getType();
        if(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {
            Tag tag  = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Wrong mime type: " + type);
        }
    } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
        String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

        for (String tech : techList) {
            if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Log.v(TAG, tag.toString());
        Log.v(TAG, tag.getTechList().toString());
    }
}

private boolean checkIfNfcEnableAndCapable() {
    if(mNfcAdapter == null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "This device doesn't support NFC");
        return false;
    }

    if(!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "NFC is disabled.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "[MainActivity]";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter(this, MainActivity.this));
}}
```

ItemDetailsActivity

```
public class ItemDetailsActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "[ItemDetailsActivity]";

private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_details);

    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.v(TAG, "Intent: " + action);

    EventItems item = (EventItems) intent.getSerializableExtra("item");

    if (item == null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "item is null");
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Item ID: " + item.getId());
        SquaredImageView imageView = (SquaredImageView) findViewById(R.id.details_picture);
        imageLoader.displayImage(item.getImageUrl(), imageView);
    }
}}
```

Please let me know what I've missed.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe sounds stupid, but maybe this link is stored on the nfc tag. What exactly is opening on Play Store, sepcial category or certain app?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I turned on debug mode on my phone and it turns out that it's looking for the application that I used to write into it.

Comment: maybe try another one and if it´s the same behaviour come back. could be a bug in that application...

Comment: What exactly did you write onto your tag (what type of NDEF records, order of records, data payload)? What package name did you define in your app manifest?